# Как в css переместить изображение влево?

Tags: изображения, css

Чтоб изображение было в левой части

```
a.rollover {
    background: url('lglogo1.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 89px;
    height: 29px; 
    padding: 0px;
   }
   a.rollover:hover {
    background: url('lglogo2.png') 0 0 no-repeat;
}
```

что-то туда нужно вставить...

Comment: Так оно должно прилепиться или ехать? Под прилипшим обычно подразумевается статичный объект, а под едущим куда-то подвижный.  
Определитесь.

Comment: Изображение итак ориентировано влево. 

    background: url('lglogo1.png') 0 0 no-repeat; 

Первый '0' - это отступ слева, второй '0' - это отступ сверху;

Comment: Это понятно, а есть другой способ?

Comment: Рискните объяснить цель этих манипуляций, тогда быстрее найдём решение.

Comment: Дело  в  том, что  в html просто пришлось картинку вместе с текстом переместить вправо (текст должен остаться в правой стороне), а картинку в html нет возможности переместить влево, поэтому нужно каким-нибудь другим способом (я решил, что через css-код картинки) переместить картинку влево.

Comment: Так чего конкретно вы хотите?

Answer (score 2):

Так так.
Во-первых - картинку или фон?
Если картинку, то извольте описывать свойства тега img для соответствующего блока и решается всё просто

```
float:left !important;
```

Если речь о фоне, то там есть возможность выравнивания

```
background:url('lglogo1.png') left top no-repeat;
```

Так что вам просто надо уточнить что именно и с каким элементом надо сделать.